# How to access old values on PrePersist LifecycleCallback in Doctrine2

Tags: php, events, doctrine, lifecycle

I have an entity in Doctrine2 and use the HasLivecycleCallbacks with PrePersist. In general this works fine, but I would like to change the version only, when certain fields in my entity change. Do I have a chance to get the old Values? Or just the keys that have been changed?

```
/**
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Person {


    /**
     * @PrePersist
     * @PreUpdate
     */
    public function increaseVersion() {


            if ( $this->version == null ) {
                $this->version = 0;
            }
            // only do this, when a certain attribute changed
            $this->version++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It depends on which LifecycleEvent we are talking about. [PrePersist and PreUpdate are different events.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345630/symfony-preupdate-vs-prepersist)

**PreUpdate** is fired before an Entity is, well, updated. This will give you a [`PreUpdateEventArgs`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.6/Doctrine/ORM/Event/PreUpdateEventArgs.html) object, which is an extended `LifecycleEventArgs` object. This will allow you to query for changed fields and give you access to the old and new value:

```
if ($event->hasChangedField('foo')) {
    $oldValue = $event->getOldValue('foo');
    $newValue = $event->getNewValue('foo');
}
```

You could also get all the changed field values through  `getEntityChangeSet()`, which would give you an array like this:

```
array(
    'foo' => array(
        0 => 'oldValue',
        1 => 'newValue'
    ),
    // more changed fields (if any) …
)
```

**PrePersist**, on the other hand, assumes a fresh Entity (think insert new row). In PrePersist, you'll get a [`LifecycleEventArgs`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/class-Doctrine.ORM.Event.LifecycleEventArgs.html) object which only has access to the Entity and the [`EntityManager`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityManager.html). In theory, you can get access to the [`UnitOfWork`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/class-Doctrine.ORM.UnitOfWork.html) (which keeps track of all the changes to Entities) through the `EntityManager`, so you could try to do

```
$changeSet = $event->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityChangeSet(
    $event->getEntity()
);
```

to get the changes for the to be persisted Entity. You could then check this array for changed fields. However, since we are talking about an insert and not an update, I assume all fields wil be considered "changed" and the old values will likely be all null. I am not sure, this will work as you need it.

Further reference: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html

Comment: Are you sure about using `prePresist`? The docs says "It should be noted that this event is only triggered on initial persist of an entity (i.e. it does not trigger on future updates)." http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events

Comment: @Martin not sure what you mean. The answer suggests to use PreUpdate instead because PrePersist "assumes a fresh entity" and "the old values will likely be null".

Comment: Well, what's the point of calling `getEntityChangeSet ()` on a fresh entity?

Comment: @Martin the OP asked how to do it with PrePersist, so I explained to him how to do that with PrePersist while at the same time explaining why this is not what he wants and what he should use instead. The point is to provide a comprehensive answer.