# Doctrine - preUpdate invokes but doesn't change a related entity property while prePersist does

Tags: symfony, doctrine, lifecycle

I am bit new to Doctrine, I found LifeCycleCallback quite useful but when I implemented I found this lacking :

I have an Author -> Book one-to-many relationship, I put `prePersist` and `preUpdate` `lifecyclecallback` event in book entity so that a property on Author entity can get changed. But I found prePersist works fine but preUpdate not able to make changes to related entity. Am I missing something here or should I register an [Event Listener & Subscriber](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) for a change in related Entity property?

Note : I am following the [Symfony doc on simple lifecycle callback](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#lifecycle-callbacks).

**Some code snippets :**

Book mapping to Author & Life cycle callback :

```
<many-to-one field="author" target-entity="Author" inversed-by="books">
    <join-columns>
        <join-column name="author_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
    </join-columns>
</many-to-one>
<lifecycle-callbacks>
    <lifecycle-callback type="prePersist" method="prePersistAction" />
    <lifecycle-callback type="preUpdate" method="preUpdateAction" />
</lifecycle-callbacks>
```

Author mapping to Book

```
<one-to-many field="books" target-entity="Book" mapped-by="author"></one-to-many>
```

On Book entity I added 2 methods to response event callback :

```
/**
 * On prePersist Event. 
 */
public function prePersistAction()
{
    $this->name = 'Some new name here';
    $this->author->setName('new Author name as per book');
}
/**
 * On preUpdate Event.
 */
public function preUpdateAction()
{
    $this->name = 'Some new name here';
    $this->author->setName('new Author name as per book');
}
```

Comment: You should post a bit of your code, at least a reduction of the important part of this two entities . We don't have the cristal ball to imagine what you are trying to do :)

Comment: Please see this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345630/symfony-preupdate-vs-prepersist

Comment: @MartinRios, Added code snippet for reference. Thanks.

Comment: Read the fine print: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate. "Changes to associations of the updated entity are never allowed in this event".  It's a bit sad but D2 events often do not work as expected even though the documentation is clear.